# How to map mnemonic to number in `iptables` `log-level` option?

Tags: iptables

The numeric `log-level` I find sometimes used in examples is ambiguous with no clear way to map only from the documentation.

#### How can I map from the log-level to the log-level number (enum value)?

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html

https://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4238.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some source for the `iptables` project at https://www.netfilter.org/downloads.html

In `iptables/extensions/libebt_log.c`, it seems to be using standard syslog macros:

```
static struct code eight_priority[] = {
  { "emerg", LOG_EMERG },
  { "alert", LOG_ALERT },
  { "crit", LOG_CRIT },
  { "error", LOG_ERR },
  { "warning", LOG_WARNING },
  { "notice", LOG_NOTICE },
  { "info", LOG_INFO },
  { "debug", LOG_DEBUG }
};
```

In most implementations of `sys/syslog.h`

```
#define LOG_EMERG 0 /* system is unusable */
#define LOG_ALERT 1 /* action must be taken immediately */
#define LOG_CRIT  2 /* critical conditions */
#define LOG_ERR   3 /* error conditions */
#define LOG_WARNING 4 /* warning conditions */
#define LOG_NOTICE  5 /* normal but significant condition */
#define LOG_INFO  6 /* informational */
#define LOG_DEBUG 7 /* debug-level messages */
```

After all that, I think it's better practice to use the mnemonic than the number for increased readability.

Answer (score 1):

iptables support also text formats.

This might be useful (tested on Bionic):

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-level debug --log-prefix INBOUND:
```

Comment: Not all builds of `iptables` it seems.